# Phpunit - code coverage - strange non-executed code on switch statement

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I am testing a method that has a `switch` statement and a couple of `case`s, the weird thing is that one of the line results not executed, a `case` line, while the content it's executed.

The picture shows the issue

[image: Case line not executed]

I was wondering how is that possible, and how can I have that line covered (my entire class results as not covered just because of that line).

Just for completition, this is an excerpt of my test

```
$this->assertRegexp('/<br>/', $scheduler->getVerboseOutput('html'));
```

Comment: Which version of PHPUnit? Which version of PHP? Which version of Xdebug? Looks like an issue in Xdebug that is likely already fixed in the current version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, `PHP 7.0.8`, `PHPUnit 4.7.6`, unfortunately I didn't figure out how to get the xdebug version, the closest thing I can get to is the zend_extension path `/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so`. I'll try to update xdebug to the latest version thank you

Comment: PHPUnit 4 is no longer supported. Please try with a current version.

Comment: Not sure of what fixed the issue, basically I updated PHPUnit to v6 and Xdebug to v2.4.0 (previosly v2.4.0RC3), it's working now thank you!

Comment: Xdebug 2.4 is still quite old. You want Xdebug 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Updating PHPUnit to v6 and Xdebug fixed the issue.

[image]

Thanks @Sebastian Bergmann